# Изменение размера текста TextView в menu android

Tags: android, android-textview, android-menu

Я в экшен бар вставил TextView таким вот образом:

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusTextview"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title=""
        />
</menu>
```

и дальше в коде

**activity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_learn, menu);
    mTextViewStatus = new TextView(this);

mTextViewStatus.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
mTextViewStatus.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
mTextViewStatus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
mTextViewStatus.setTextSize(12);
menu.add(0, R.id.statusTextview, 1, " ").setActionView(mTextViewStatus).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**картинка для наглядности**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос:**  как можно задать размер шрифта,стиль, цвет - в xml?

Comment: В разметке вы указываете параметр showAsAction="ifRoom", а в коде меняете на "always" - в этом есть какой то скрытый смысл? Почему бы не указать в разметке сразу showAsAction="always", а в коде не указывать ничего, позволив процессору чуток расслабиться :)

Comment: @pavlofff только заметил. до этого не обращал внимания, так как копировал код с примера) По моему вопросу есть идеи как это моно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

примерно как то так можно - напишите для своего `TextView` нужный стиль и примените его.

```
mTextViewStatus.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ActionTextStyle);
```

**Style.xml:**

```
<style name="ActionTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"> >
        <item name="android:textColor">#A85E4F</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: mTextViewStatus.setTextAppearance(R.style.ActionTextStyle) - просит добавить аннотацию targenApi(M) - работает только на последней версии андроида?

Comment: А .. до API 23 используется конструктор с контекстом. Исправил.

Comment: Пардон, а вы изменили ответ? я не вижу изменений!

Comment: но [они есть](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/488101/revisions) :)

Comment: так.. это сработало!)